# Joining aggregated to non aggregated data

Tags: postgresql

I have the following two tables

```
Key          |Clicks |Impressions|
-------------+-------+-----------+
USA-SIM-CARDS|55667  |544343     |


     Key          |Conversions |State|
 -----------------+------------+------
 USA-SIM-CARDS    | 456        |NJ
 USA-SIM-CARDS    |2           |FL
 USA-SIM-CARDS    |56          |AK
 USA-SIM-CARDS    |23          |MY
```

I would like the following output

```
     Key          |Conversions |Clicks |Impressions|
 -----------------+------------+- -----+-----------+
 USA-SIM-CARDS    | 537        |  55667|544343
```

Is it possible to accomplish this through a join or would I have to resort to looping the data?

Many thanks.

Comment: You should post whatever attempts you have made at solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT f.key, f.clicks, f.impressions, sum( s.Conversions) As Conversions
FROM first_table f
JOIN second_table s
-- also LEFT JOIN can be used if you want to get rows from F 
-- even when there are no any corresponding rows in S
ON f.Key = s.Key
Group By f.key, f.clicks, f.impressions
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7864e/2